# Do not display data output in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote the following code snippet for Ajax connections, but unfortunately the return value is not displayed in the output, but it does not give a special warning to understand the meaning. Please help.

**js**

```
$("#search").on('keyup', function(){var value = $(this).val();
  $.ajax('feed.php',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      keyword: value
    },
    success: function(data){
      $("#pre").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

**feed.php**

```
<?php
require_once('main.php');
$db = Db::getInstance();
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$records = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dic_word WHERE word LIKE '%$keyword%'");

$out['html']= '';
foreach($records as $record){
  $out['html'] .= $record['word'] . '<br>';
}

echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change .success to  `.done(function() { 
   $("#pre").html(data);
  })
  .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });`

Comment: try `$("#pre").html(data.html);`

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
jQuery('#search').on('keyup', () => {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'feed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { keyword: jQuery(this).val() },
        success: response => {
            jQuery('#pre').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

feed.php

```
<?php
require_once('main.php');
$database = Db::getInstance();
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$records = $database->query("SELECT * FROM dic_word WHERE word LIKE '%$keyword%'");
$output = '';
foreach($records as $record){
    $output .= $record['word'] . '<br />';
}
echo($output);
?>
```

**PS:** You don't need to use json output absolutly. But if there is coercion to using json output, the problem is 2 following items:

1. You don't set the output "Content-Type" to json: ***header('Content-Type: application/json');***
2. You shouldn't pass the json object to html method in jQuery and should parsing it at first with JSON.parse(response) class, then with foreach, for or anything else process it